# “warning: Text page X contains only floats.” How to suppress this warning?

Tags: warnings

When there are only floats on page, I get the following message: "warning: Text page X contains only floats.". I'd like to suppress this warning. I know that I could use `p` parameter: `\begin{table}[!htp]`, but I still want the whole page to be handled like normal text page, not like page of floats. Any ideas?

Comment: apart from having floats in what way do you _not_ want the page to be a float page, by default page style etc are identical.

Comment: The message is not coming from a macro but is directly coded in the tokens in the `\output` register so you would need to copy that omitting the warning.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is explained here http://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html.
You may find that simply adding

```
\clearpage
```

before you begin with your figures will get rid of the warning.

Comment: Worth noting that this solution forces a page break before the image. Without the `\clearpage`, the text flow continues and the image is included as soon as the next page break (naturally) happens.

Comment: The link does not say why there is a warning and how to get rid of it.

Comment: @jaruah, the link leads to a document that not only explains the problem, but also talks about the solution I mentioned above, see 4th section beginning with "If you find that liberal values of the float parameters still are causing trouble, you can try forcing a float page with \clearpage to disgorge the accumulated blockage."

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get rid of the warning, you can use the [`silence`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page 8 contains only floats}
```

replace `8` with the actual page number appearing in the warning message. You could also use

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
```

to suppress *all* warnings beginning with the string `Text page`.

Or, better yet, you can use `\WarningFilter*` (note the star) to silence the messages by the way they are constructed:

```
\WarningFilter*{latex}{Text page \thepage\space contains only floats}
```

The following example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

%\WarningFilter*{latex}{Text page \thepage\space contains only floats}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hb]
\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-40]

\end{document}
```

gives the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Text page 8 contains only floats.
```

uncomment the line with the `\WarningFilter*` command and the warning will vanish.

You can also check [the silence package documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/silence/silence-doc.pdf) for more info.

Comment: This does solve the problem of silencing the warning. However, this does not explain the nature of said warning, which could have roots on a problem with the code itself.

Answer (score 4):

(Not enough reputation to comment.) I just had the same problem, and removing the location specifiers (e.g. [!tb]) solved the issue for me.

Using `\clearpage` as mentioned in other answers resulted in a large undesired white space.

Comment: This answer solved my problem!